# Use custom TestNG.xml file instead of the one generated automatically?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testng

I have a `Maven`/`TestNG`/`Selenium` project in `Eclipse`.  When I run the project as a `TestNG` test, I see this in the console:

```
[TestNG] Running:    
    /private/var/folders/ly/hg5d7s916xs2f9c1l95ndqcm0000gn/T/testng-eclipse-1560914389/testng-customsuite.xml
```

Awesome.  So I copied that file to the top level folder (next to my `pom.xml`), and re-ran the project.  But I see this:

```
[TestNG] Running:
    /private/var/folders/ly/hg5d7s916xs2f9c1l95ndqcm0000gn/T/testng-eclipse-631698178/testng-customsuite.xml
```

It generated a new XML file.  But, I need to set parameters and other things for my tests to run in a distributed fashion.  How can I use the XML file that I edited?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own file called `testng.xml` and put it in the `src/test/resources`.

You might need to install the maven-surefire-plugin in order to make that work additionally.

```
<plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

**Update**

If you want to specify custom suite from Eclipse, then you have to go to

`Debug Configuration -> New TestNG Test -> Suite`

Once you select the Suite option you can choose any suite xml file which is inside your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I added a file called `testng.xml` to `src/test/resources` and added the above xml lines to the `<build>` section of the pom.xml.  I should have the surefire plugin installed because it's generating test reports in the `target/surefire-reports` folder, but other than that I don't know where to check.  However, when `Run As` `TestNG Test`, I still see in the console that it's generating a new XML file in `/private/var/...`

Comment: Run As TestNG Test.. so you run it directly from eclipse?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing.

Comment: Great!  That did it!  Out of curiosity, do you know how to add `Suite` to the list `Run As` options when I right click on the project?

Comment: Not sure if you can do that.. but on the top panel.. you have the debug button.. and when you extend it you will have your custom testng test with a certain suite.. you can re-run it from there as many time s as u want

Comment: If my answers were of value to you i would appreciate you accepting the post. Thanks

Comment: @MaciejKowalski - Is src/test/resources the standard location for keeping testng xml suite files ?